# Copy Homepage URL After '='

Tags: php

I want to copy Homepage URL After **=**

I am using this code

```
echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

But it is copying the Whole URL i.e., `https://example.com/?link=$1`

I want just Value of **$1**

Answer (score 0):

To echo out the value after the '=' you'll need to use $_GET['']. So in your example:

```
echo $_GET['link'];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, but you can use it

```
$url = "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=wm&ogbl";
$array_url = explode("=",$url);
echo $array_url[1];
```

output : https://paiza.io/projects/9HEmUcCM3UZqYEm3OhQe_Q